# Is removing huge data for time series model right?

Tags: time-series

I have time-series data that contains nearly 90% zero or null values. Is removing these values correct? After removing them, the dataset will not have a constant time difference between samples.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is yes.

For the long answer, you should read this [article](https://cardoai.com/handling-missing-data-with-python/), which I have also read it recently (thanks to other users here).